# C# Add new entry to a List<string> without overwriting the old value

Tags: c#, list

However my issue is on every iteration the Old "line" value is just being overwritten.

I'll explain the code below.

```
public class Session
{
    public String SessionId { get; set; }
    public List<String> SessionLog { get; set; }

    public Session()
    {
        SessionLog = new List<String>();
    }
}


public List<Session> sessionMasterList = new List<Session>();
```

I have code that parses a file and obtains sessionID's and puts them into a distinct session ID list.

I then create a new session objection and add populate the session1.SessionID value and then write that to the sessionMasterList.

```
 List<String> distinctSessionID; 
 distinctSessionID = sessionIDList.Distinct().ToList();
 Session session1 = new Session();
 session1.SessionId = value;
 sessionMasterList.Add(session1);
```

Later on in my code I go though another file so I can populate the SessionLog. I loop thought the sessionMasterList and compare sessionMasterList[i].SessionId with a sessionID.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < sessionMasterList.Count; i++)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(sessionMasterList[i].SessionId);
   if(sessionMasterList[i].SessionId == sID)
  {
  sessionMasterList[i].SessionLog.Add(line);
  }
 }
```

If the SessionMasterList[i].SessionID matches sID, then I want to add SessionLog to the arraylist of SessionLogs for that sessionID.

However my issue is on every iteration the Old value is just being overwritten with the new one found for SEssionLogs.

How do i get a new entry for SessionLogs for the SessionID in the loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - something we can copy & paste into a console app that reproduces your problem when we hit run.

Comment: Are you doing `session1.SessionId = value;` inside a loop? can you show such loop?

Comment: This cannot compile outside of a class in C#:  `public List<Session> sessionMasterList = new List<Session>();`

Comment: Using the keyword 'new' will destroy old values.

Comment: The loop is the for loop up there.  So it files the SessionID in the session Master list.  It's all warapped in a while loop reading a file.

Comment: I don't want to destory the old value

Comment: I want to add a new record to that list

Comment: sessionMasterList[i].SessionLog.Add(line); This part here just keeps over writing the old value with the new value.  How can I just have it add a new record since it's a list?

Comment: We know, but how did you check that it is really overwrited ?

Comment: Add() method is not overwriting. My guess is that you are not checking correctly in the first place, or you are not loading the SessioLogs correctly in the first place and it is empty before the first add

Comment: When I step though the code, I see see the add is just overwriting it with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
sessionMasterList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.SessionId==sID)?.SessionLog.Add(line)
```

I would still suggest using a dictionaty instead of a list, this way you would make, remove the possibility of duplicate objects. Also it would reduce the number of operations and it would run in logN time and not in N.

something like this

```
var sessionMaster = Dictionary<string, Session>();
sessionMaster[sid]?.SessionLog.Add(line);
```

EDIT:
try this

```
var sessionMaster = Dictionary<string, Session>();

sessionMaster.Add("1", new Session(){SessiongLogs= new List<string>(){"a", "b"}};
sessionMaster.Add("2", new Session(){SessiongLogs= new List<string>(){"c", "d"}};

var sid = "1";
var line = "testLine"
sessionMaster[sid]?.SessionLog.Add(line);
```

Comment: That wont work, he want to iterate all the sessionMasterList. This will only change the first.

Comment: yeah I just tested that.  When I check the SessionMaster list I see [0] SesisonId 1 (correct value), then SessionLog [0] and the value is the new value.   What i want is SEssionLog[0] value SessionLog[1] value.  etc.

Comment: The log that I am parsing prints multiple log lines all with the same sessionID.

Comment: It makes more sense to me to have a unique sessionID, and then a list of Logs that belong to this session.

Comment: I am guessing you are testing it in a wrong way, or you are not initially populating the sessionList.

Comment: Let me do some more tesing and debugging to see if you right.

Comment: try the part I added after "EDIT:"